# How can i add a condition in a modal using bootstrap-4-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I need to add a condition in a modal using bootstrap-4-react, but the modal always appears without respecting the condition used. I will show what I have at this moment:

```
import Boostrap, { Modal } from 'bootstrap-4-react';
.
.
.
class Home extends Component {
.
.
.
componentDidMount() {
    Boostrap.modal("#signupModal", 'toggle')
  }
.
.
.
    render() {
      return (
         <div className="Home">
          <Modal show={achieveDreams && achieveDreams.length === 0} id="signupModal" fade>
            <Modal.Dialog>
              <Modal.Content>
                <Modal.Header>
                  <Modal.Title>
                <strong style={{ color: "#fff" }}>{"¡congratulation!".toUpperCase()}</strong>
                  </Modal.Title>
                  <Modal.Close>
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </Modal.Close>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                  Activate button.
                </Modal.Body>
              </Modal.Content>
            </Modal.Dialog>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

At this moment when I run this develompent the error throw in the console is the next:

[image: Warning in console]

**Currently the condition is not working as expected. If someone knows how to condition the mode in the right way, I would greatly appreciate it.**

Comment: Hi jaimeduque17, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ravibagul91no man, your solution does not help me. I don`t understand what is wrong, let me show you the print of the values included in the condition.

"achieveDreams false"
"achieveDreams.lenth 0"

The modal must be appear when the above is true.

Comment: In that case your if condition is somethng like, `if(this.state.achieveDreams && this.state.achieveDreams.length === 0)`.

Comment: @ravibagul91I could finally make the condition work, what I did was to include the condition in the WillRecieveProps and I deleted the componentDidMount, but now I have another problem, when the modal loads for the first time it is shown but removed instantly, but if I Refresh for second time the page if it works as expected. Do you suddenly know how I can correct this behavior?

Comment: Which condition you used in `WillRecieveProps`?

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    const { achieveDreams = []} = { ...newProps }
    achieveDreams.length === 0  && Boostrap.modal("#signupModal", 'toggle')
  }`

Comment: You are getting `achieveDreams` in props correct?

Comment: @ravibagul91Yes.

Comment: Did you check my comment in answer //if `achieveDreams` is coming from `props` you should use `this.props.achieveDreams && this.props.achieveDreams.length !== 0`. Check that comment and try to implement `componentDidMount` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As the warning already suggested, you should do this,

```
show={achieveDreams && achieveDreams.length === 0 ? true : false}
```

**Note:** I doubt this condition `achieveDreams && achieveDreams.length === 0`.

What this condition is, **if `achieveDreams` (has value / is not null) AND `achieveDreams.length === 0`**.

So I think this condition always be `false`, your condition should be this,

```
show={achieveDreams && achieveDreams.length !== 0 ? true : false}
```

---

**Update**

From the [docs](https://bootstrap-4-react.com/#documentation/components/modal),

I didn't see any usecase as you are using, from the docs we can see you have only 2 option's of using modal.

1. Via data attributes,

   `<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>`
2. Via JavaScript,

   `Bootstrap.modal('#myModal', options);`

So, your attempt of using `show` prop on modal is stand's invalid here. **Using `show` prop on modal has no effect on your modal, you should remove it**.

Your modal is getting displayed due to `Bootstrap.modal('#myModal', options);` in `componentDidMount`.

You should have condition in `componentDidMount` like,

```
componentDidMount() {
  //considering `achieveDreams` is in state only, 
  //if `achieveDreams` is coming from `props` you should use `this.props.achieveDreams && this.props.achieveDreams.length !== 0`
  if(this.state.achieveDreams && this.state.achieveDreams.length !== 0){ 
     Boostrap.modal("#signupModal", 'toggle')
  }   
}
```

---

**Update 2**

As per the comment *"achieveDreams false" "achieveDreams.lenth 0" The modal must be appear when the above is true.*

You condition must be this,

```
componentDidMount() {
  //considering `achieveDreams` is in state only, 
  //if `achieveDreams` is coming from `props` you should use `this.props.achieveDreams && this.props.achieveDreams.length === 0`
  if(this.state.achieveDreams && this.state.achieveDreams.length === 0){ 
     Boostrap.modal("#signupModal", 'toggle')
  }   
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xcnacp)

Comment: wouldn't this be simple `{!!(achieveDreams && achieveDreams.length)}`

Comment: @jaimeduque17, check the updated answer and demo link.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see achieveDreams is not defined, please try to use `this.state.achieveDreams && this.state.achieveDreams.length === 0` and it will work fine.

For reference, you can have a look at the following sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-bash-6e2wq

Note: You are mounting the modal in componentDidMount so it will always appear, show condition will not work as expected, you also have to add a condition in componentDidMount as follows:

```
if (this.state.achieveDreams && this.state.achieveDreams.length === 0) {
    Boostrap.modal("#signupModal", "toggle");
}
```

Comment: in my case, achieveDreams is a prop, not a state.

Comment: so rather than the state you can use the prop